# Redirection issue for staging environment in existing production environment in Laravel + Angular 2

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, .htaccess, amazon-ec2

I have Laravel 5.2 and Angular 2 project setup and currently running on /var/www/html/ directory in AWS server with IP address http://xx.xx.xx.xx which points to /var/www/html/public/ in apache config.

So my production server structure in /var/www/html/ will look like:

```
    app
    artisan
    bootstrap
    cgi-bin
    composer.json
    composer.lock
    composer.phar
    config
    database
    gulpfile.js
    package.json
    phpunit.xml
    public
    README.md
    resources
    server.php
    storage
    tests
    vendor
```

Now I want to create staging server in /var/www/html/. so I have created the new staging directory in /var/www/html/ and put all code into the staging directory.

```
    |-- app
    |-- artisan
    |-- bootstrap
    |-- cgi-bin
    |-- composer.json
    |-- composer.lock
    |-- composer.phar
    |-- config
    |-- database
    |-- gulpfile.js
    |-- package.json
    |-- phpunit.xml
    |-- public
    |-- README.md
    |-- resources
    |-- server.php
    |-- staging
        |-- app
        |-- artisan
        |-- bootstrap
        |-- cgi-bin
        |-- composer.json
        |-- composer.lock
        |-- composer.phar
        |-- config
        |-- database
        |-- gulpfile.js
        |-- package.json
        |-- phpunit.xml
        |-- public
        |-- README.md
        |-- resources
        |-- server.php
        |-- storage
        |-- tests
        |-- vendor
    |-- storage
    |-- tests
    |-- vendor
```

I have already put the staging code into "/var/www/html/staging/" path but when request from production server call it will point to  /var/www/html/public/ path.

So How I can access staging environment without creating virtual hosts? What htaccess rules do I need to add?

Any ideas how I can achieve this ??

Answer (score 0):

You must put the files to /var/www/html/staging, then you can access it by http://xx.xx.xx.xx/staging/

Comment: I have already put the staging code into "/var/www/html/staging/" path but when request from production server called it will point to /var/www/html/public/ path.

So How I can access staging environment without creating virtual hosts? What htaccess rules do I need to add?

Any ideas how I can achieve this ??